# InfluxDB API query request returning html and not JSON response

Tags: json, api, curl, influxdb

I would like to download data using the Influxdb API and curl. I followed the documentations here: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/guides/querying_data/

However, instead of getting a JSON response and am getting a html response that looks like:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Chronograf</title>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/images/favicon.ico"   
           type="image/x-icon" />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link  
           href="/chronograf.17046cbf9b59fc1b5280.css"  
           rel="stylesheet"></head>
     <body>
     <div id='react-root' data-basepath=""></div>
     <script type="text/javascript"  
     src="/app.17046cbf9b59fc1b5280.js"></script><script  
     type="text/javascript"  
     src="/vendor.25a088bac218975a0bac.js"></script></body>
   </html>
```

I am new to curl and calling an API. My end goal is to automatically download the csv files from Influx. I tried to use Postman and Python, however, due to corporate proxy issues, I am only able to make curl work.

My questions are:

1. How do I get the JSON response like in the documentations?
2. Is there a better way to solve my problem with downloading the data from Influx?